# Sorting a list of object by field, and if it's null, by another field

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a list of object, DealPortafoglio. This object has three fields: keySum1, keySum2 and key. I would like to sort the List by keySum1, and if it's null, by keySum2. 
How can I use the Comparable interface to do that?
Thank you in advance

At this moment, the only way I found is to split the list into two lists (one with keySum1 != null and the other with keySum1=null and keySum2 != null) and sort them indipendently.

Comment: How about if the field is null for one object in the list, but not for another object it is being compared with...?

Comment: Well, you simply create the correct `Comparator` which uses whatever logic you want when comparing two instances... we cannot really help you implementing it since it's not 100% clear how you want to compare these objects...  if you compare an instance where `keySum1` is null with one where it isn't what should happen? Should be simply compare `keySum2` with `keySum1`? Should we compare the two `keysum2`s? Should we always consider the object with `keySum1` as "smaller"? All of these are valid logics that depend on the result you want...

Comment: As other said, create a custom comparator and implement your logic. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `Comparator.nullsLast()` with `Comparator.thenComparing()`.

For example for

```
@Data
class MyObject {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
}
```

you can create a `Comparator` like this:

```
Comparator<MyObject> combined =
    Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getField1, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
    .thenComparing(MyObject::getField2, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
    .thenComparing(MyObject::getField3, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

This will result in a `Comparator` that first sorts by `field1`; if it contains `null` for one of the compared objects contain `null`, it will be sorted after the other (`nullsLast`). If the field is `null` for both objects, the next field will be evaluated (`thenComparing()`), until `field3` is reached.

You can of course create a helper method

```
private static Comparator<MyObject> compareField(Function<MyObject, String> fieldExtractor) {
    return Comparator.comparing(fieldExtractor, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
}
```

so your combination comparator definition is shorter:

```
Comparator<MyObject> combined =
    compareField(MyObject::getField1)
        .thenComparing(compareField(MyObject::getField2))
        .thenComparing(compareField(MyObject::getField3));
```